# Unable to print bibliography, citations come up as 'undefined'

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

Although I have defined the bibliography in my `.bib` file, my LaTeX file doesn't seem to be accepting it. I'm also using NatBib for citations.

Here is the part of my LaTeX document where I'm getting the error:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\citep{atkins}
```

Here is my `.bib` file:

```
@misc{atkins,
author = "James Domone",
title = " The challenges and benefits of the electrification of aircraft",
url = "https://www.atkinsglobal.com/~/media/Files/A/Atkins-Corporate/Electrification White Paper - digital.pdf"
}
```

Here's the error log:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `atkins' on page 2 undefined on input line 80.
....
Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.
```

These are the packages I'm using:

```
\documentclass[journal]{new-aiaa}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable,tabularx}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

ABCDEF.\citep{atkins}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
```

I'm new to LaTeX, and I could really use your help to understand where I went wrong. Thank you very much!

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/82917)  starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. This makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you.

Comment: Did you run `latex`+`bibtex`+`latex`+`latex`?

Comment: @campa I tried what you suggested, it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: \documentclass[journal] ?

Comment: @Fran it's part of a format provided by the journal I am submitting to. Here are more details, if you need them: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/preparation-of-papers-for-aiaa-technical-conferences/rsssbwthkptn

Comment: @GanTheMan I see that you don't see it. The code that you posted is  wrong in the first line, missing the mandatory argument of `\documentclass`, and therefore what you posted is not a "working" example.  Please edit the answer to show a MWEB that  show the issue of the question but only the issue of the question, without the need of debug investigating in external  (tomorrow broken) links.

Comment: @Fran I have fixed the argument for \documentclass

Comment: @Fran I've managed to resolve my issues. I think it might have been a problem with my editor or something. But thank you very much for your help and attention to this problem! :)